# How to Clear DataStore Preference and Room data in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack-datastore

I am developing an Android App. I need to clear the data programmatically including the datastore preferences and room data when i press a button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reading through the developer guides should make this fairly straight forward...

Comment: Which data? Please be a tiny bit more specific...

Answer (score 4):

To clear the Shared Prefrences :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cda-preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

and use the delete query for the database :)